# tftpd-hpa doesn't work with a tftp client on another pc in my lan

Tags: networking, server, tftp

I have a PC running Ubuntu 19.04.  (IP: 192.168.109.113).
My tftp is running successfully and my local tftp client is working

```
root@server:/# tftp 192.168.109.113
tftp> get
(files) test.txt
tftp>
```

but with a tftp client on another pc in my lan tftp isn't working.
I allways get a time out. Ping is ok and firewall (UFW) is disabled.

When I try to fetch data from the server with my windows machine it fails like so:

```
C:\>tftp 192.168.109.113 put test.txt
Timeout occurred
 Connect request failed
```

when I put a file it actually gets created in /var/lib/tftpboot but not filled with data.

Here are the contents of /etc/default/tftpd-hpa:

```
# /etc/default/tftpd-hpa

TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure --create"
```

Here is /etc/xinetd.d/tftp:

```
service tftp
{
protocol = udp
port = 69
socket_type = dgram
wait = yes
user = nobody
server = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
server_args = /var/lib/tftpboot
disable = no
}
```

Here is output to `iptables --list`:

```
root@server:/# iptables --list
iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:69
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:tftp

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:69
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:tftp
```

Any Idea what I must do to get tftp running for all clients?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **;-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the output to `iptables --list`. Then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: @Fabby I have added the info thank you so much for your response to the question 

Comment: I only noticed now `disable = yes`...  Can you try by changing that to `no`?  (It's definitely not your software firewall)

Comment: @Fabby I have changed that but it didn't help the same problem still persists.

Comment: Then I'm all out of ideas, sorry...

Comment: I know it's a long time back, but have you ever solved this?